# Significant Digits for different units

Tags: measurements, units, approximations

I read,

[image]

From (iv), 12.3 has three significant figures. And from (v) we can infer that 12.30 has four significant figures. So let's say it's meters, then 12.30 m = 1230 cm = 12300 mm

But 1230 and 12300 should also have the same number of significant figures, that is, equal to 4. But how would one figure that out? Or would they have less number of significant figures, which would be against (vi)

Comment: Vote to close : I think this is a question about mathematics, not physics. Also, I think you are pointing out a contradiction in a particular set of rules you have been given. The difficulty is the rules, not mathematics.

Comment: @sammygerbil When I was in school, significant figures was a tool provided to me in physics class because it was designed to help us pay attention to the errors in our measurement.  My mathematics courses never touched the concept because it had no use in mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this is "whatever you teacher wants the answer to be."

Significant figures is a powerful tool for quickly portraying the precision of your numbers.  However, the "rules" of how write them are not as hard and fast as this book may make it appear.  When I went through school, our rules were different than those provided here.

In the rules I was given, trailing 0's were indeed significant.  If it were any other way, I would be capable of showing that I had measured 1.001m to within a single millimeter (4 sig figs), but I would be incapable of showing that I had measured 1.000m to the same precision.  By the rules you showed above, I would have to claim the latter only had 1 significant figure, even if I had indeed taken the measurement to within a millimeter, but by the version I learned, that measurement also has 4 sig figs.

The drawback of the version I learned is that if I measured something to be 11m long, and converted that to mm, the number would be 11000mm.  The rules I was given would suggest that 11000mm has 5 sig figs, which would give the illusion that I somehow increased precision by changing my units!  This is a place where your book's approach has an advantage.  Changing units doesn't change the significant figures.  The solution I was taught to this was to use scientific notation.  I was expected to write that as 1.1*10^4mm, which keeps the number of significant figures at 2.  I often had to use scientific notation for silly numbers (3.0*10^2 rather than 300) simply because that was the only tool we had to preserve sig figs under our rules.

I was also taught that the rules changed if you were measuring the logarithm of a value.  In logarithms, I was taught that the numbers before the decimal place are *not* significant figures.  Why?  Well if you think about it, the integer part of the logarithm is an exponent.  If I were to measure the above 1.1*10^4mm on a logarithmic scale, the answer would be 4.04 dBmm.  The leading 4 is associated with the 10^4 in the original value, which was the argument given for why it didn't count as a sig fig.

And of course, even the rules I was taught are not fully consistent.  If I am measuring a sound level in dB, my sound meter provides a precision guarantee in dB, so any reading I get from the meter should count all digits as sig figs?! Maybe?!  It's not so clear.

In real scientific literature, such as journals, you are encouraged to provide your actual error margins rather than merely relying on significant figures to give you an order of magnitude estimation of the errors.  Providing the real error terms sidesteps the entire mess that significant figures creates.

So, if you're in a class, ask your teacher what they would like to see.  Most often we teach sig figs simply to get people used to the idea of actually tracking the precision of their measurements rather than blindly claiming that my 11m measurement is 4.041392685158225040750199971243 dBmm because that's what I got when I plugged it into my calculator.  Just ask and find out how your teacher wants it handled.  If you're not in a class, and just learning from a book, just take sig figs with a grain of salt.  They're just a tool to help.  Use them when they're helpful, but recognize that they're generally abandoned as you get into the higher levels.

Comment: I really like the scientific notation and trailing 0's as significant specifically because it allows you to express situations like the one in this question.  It's really interesting when you realize that significant digits don't really apply directly, and that's just assuming the reported values are accurate without considering device accuracy and measurement uncertainty.

Comment: RE: " I would be incapable of showing that I had measured 1.000m to the same precision." Yes, you could. You could write "1.000 m" (because trailing zeros are significant if a decimal point is present) or even "1000. mm" (which is different under these rules than "1000 mm").

Comment: Admittedly the "1000. mm" version is a very subtle distinction that would be likely to lead to a lot of errors of communication, and "1000 mm +/- 0.5 mm" would be much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

What you are discovering is that "implicitly indicating uncertainty" (which is essentially what your rules facilitate) is inherently limited. Specifically, the rule "trailing zeros without a decimal point don't count" means that you cannot express correctly express a number and its uncertainty in mm if the uncertainty is greater than 10 mm.

All these things are conventions - and conventions are there to make life easier. When exceptions occur, you just need to make a sensible adjustment. If you need to quote your result in mm, then you can just use exponential (or scientific) notation. Or if you really insist on using integer representation, you can explicitly add the error:

$$\rm{12.30~ m\\
1230~cm\\
1.230 \cdot 10^{4}~mm\\
12300 ± 10~mm}$$

Finally, sometimes people will put parentheses around the uncertain digits in an answer. For example, the [NIST value for the Planck constant](https://www.nist.gov/sites/default/files/documents/pml/div684/fcdc/wallet2014.pdf) is

$$h=6.626~070~040(81)×10^{−34}~\rm{J~s}$$

This is shorthand for $h=h=(6.626~070~040±0.000~000~081)×10^{−34}~\rm{J~s}$

(see [NIST website](http://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Info/Constants/definitions.html) ). Obviously when you have a lot of significant digits (as with these highly accurate physical constants) this kind of notation starts to make a lot of sense.

Finally, you might want to look at this [excellent primer on uncertainty estimation and propagation](http://www.webassign.net/question_assets/unccolphysmechl1/measurements/manual.html)