# Question about extra zeros in measurement

Tags: measurements

I most often encounter data values in problems which have some meaningless looking zeros after the decimal point at the end. There is no non-zero number to the right of the zeros. For example, the length of a pencil is given $7.00 cm$. Why do we have those zeros at the end? What's their purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Those zeros are a quick way to indicate precision in a value. They imply that the number is accurate "to the last digit".

This means that 10.0 is 10.0+-0.1 (1% accuracy) while 10.000 is 10.000 +- 0.001

You may be interested in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/323239/26969) and the related answers and links.

Comment: So do we need to really worry about the precision even when we just solve problems?

Comment: Yes - because the precision of your answer should match the precision of the information you are given. This is a very important part of science - know the error in your data. You learn this when solving problems - so you will apply it properly when you tackle real world issues. Example - if I tell you it took 2.0 seconds for an object to drop 20 m and I ask you to calculate g, your answer would be 10 m/s/s - not 10.0; if I told you it took 2.00 seconds to drop 19.62 m you could say g=9.81 m/s/s

Comment: So if we say that the length of a pencil, for example, is $7.00cm$, this means that we are sure that the length is within the first hundredth of a centimeter above seven.

Comment: @user41736 yes that is what is implied. Where "sure" usually has some statistical meaning. See links in the answer I referenced.